# Get pattern ae|ea|s3 to replace characters in string in python

Tags: python

I want to give encoding instructions  ‘ae|ea|s3’, where a is replaced by e, e is replace by a and s is replaced by 3 for the same string. But I am having problem to write a program to insert pattern chr replaced by chr1|chr2 replaced by chr3|chr4 replaced by chr5. for the above pattern chr, chr2 and chr4 are characters from the string i want to replace by chr1, chr3,chr5 and "|" represents "and". I have searched google but couldnt find any hints regarding the above problem.

```
def encode(filename):

  path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
  basename = "assgn2part1.txt"
  filename = path + "\\" + basename
  #file = open(filename, "rt")
  f = open(filename)
  contents = f.read()
  print contents ,"\n"
  chars = ["a","b","e","3","d","r","g","j","h","i"]

  newcontents = contents.translate(string.maketrans("aes","ea3"))

  print newcontents
```

The answer I get is:

```
  This is a message 

  Thi3 i3 e ma33ega
```

This does give the result, but I want to insert the pattern in the definition itself

```
  encode("ae|ea|s3","C:\Users\user\Desktop\\assgn2part1.txt")
```

to give me the result and I should be able to substitute it with another type of pattern like

```
  encode("hc|m3|te","C:\Users\user\Desktop\\assgn2part1.txt")
```

I have tried very hard but not able to get solution for this. Please help me

Comment: Why can't you just make it take 3 arguments, the first two being the strings passed to maketrans?

Answer (score 2):

Use this to turn `"hc|m3|te"` into the translation table:

```
def parse_into_translation_table(s):
    return string.maketrans(*map(''.join,zip(*map(list,s.split('|')))))
```

See that:

```
>>> map(''.join,zip(*map(list,"hc|m3|te".split('|'))))
['hmt', 'c3e']
```

is the form needed to give to `string.maketrans`.

Example:

```
>>> parse_into_translation_table("hc|m3|te")
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefgcijkl3nopqrseuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

To show how this is used in your `encode` function:

```
def encode(substitutions, filename):

   # ... file reading  ...

   newcontents = contents.translate(parse_into_translation_table(substitutions))

   return newcontents
```

Comment: I am sorry, but i didnt get the above method. I am new to python and i am not able to apply this properly in my program. i want to make a pattern which replaces characters. eg instead of hc|m3|te i write encode("ma|te|ga","C:\Users\user\Desktop\\assgn2part1.txt"), will it work for that as well. how do i define the pattern