# what is wrong with my encoding/cipher code?

Tags: python, encode, encryption

My code that is meant to replace certain letters (a with e, e with a and s with 3 specifically) is not working, but I am not quite sure what the error is as it is not changing the text file i am feeding it.

```
pattern = "ae|ea|s3"

def encode(pattern, filename):
  message = open(filename, 'r+')
  output = []
  pattern2 = pattern.split('|')
  for letter in message:
    isfound = false
    for keypair in pattern2:
      if letter == keypair[0]: 
        output.append(keypair[1])
        isfound = true
      if isfound == true:
       break;
    if isfound == false:
      output.append(letter)

  message.close()
```

Been racking my brain out trying to figure this out for a while now..

Comment: A common homework? [How can I make this program more efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845988/how-can-i-make-this-program-more-efficient)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get pattern ae|ea|s3 to replace characters in string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645383/get-pattern-aeeas3-to-replace-characters-in-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick implementation with the desired result, you will need to modify it yourself to read files, etc:

```
def encode(pattern, string):
    rep = {}
    for pair in pattern.split("|"):
        rep[pair[0]] = pair[1]

    out = []
    for c in string:
        out.append(rep.get(c, c))

    return "".join(out)

print encode("ae|ea|s3", "Hello, this is my default string to replace")
#output => "Hallo, thi3 i3 my dafeult 3tring to rapleca"
```

If you want to modify a file, you need to specifically tell your program to write to the file. Simply appending to your output variable will not change it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not changing the textfile because you do not replace the textfile with the `output` you create. Instead this function is creating the `output` string and dropping it at the end of the function. Either return the `output` string from the function and store it outside, or replace the file in the function by writing to the file without appending.

As this seems like an exercise I prefer to not add the code to do it, as you will probably learn more from writing the function yourself.